# Searching 2000+ xml records with javascript locks up browser

Tags: javascript, xml

My client wants to create a search form for entries in a static xml file he has, and doesn't want to use server-side technologies. He wants it to just use javascript in the browser. What i have works, except that if you search for something that has a LOT of matching entries, it locks up the browser for a bit. How can I prevent this? Here's what I have:

```
$(function(){
    var root, searchEvent = setTimeout(function(){}, 0);
    $.get('allitems.xml', function(xml){
        root = $(xml);
    });

    $('#search-field').on('keyup', function(e){
        clearTimeout(searchEvent);
        searchEvent = setTimeout($.proxy(function(){search($(this).val());}, this), 500);
    });

    function search(q){
        var results = 0;
        $('#searchResults').empty();

        root.find('Beskrivning').each(function(i, el){
            /*if(results > 9)
                return false;*/
            el = $(el);
            if(el.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(q) != -1){
                addToResults(el.parent());
                results++;
            }
        });
    }
    function addToResults(node){
        var div = $('<a>').attr(
                'href', 
                'http://www.pn-trading.se/Objekt/tabid/125/' +
                    (node.find('ID').text()) +
                    '/123055/auktion/' +
                    (node.find('paplatsnamn').text()) +
                    '/Default.aspx?tabselect=' +
                    (node.find('paplatsnamn').text())
            )
            .attr('target', '_blank')
            .addClass('sr-item')
            .append(
                $('<div>').addClass('sr-item-image').append(
                    $('<img>').attr(
                        'src', 
                        'http://www.pn-trading.se/Portals/0/' +
                            (node.find('katalog').text()) +
                            '/' + (node.find('bildnr').text()) + '-200.jpg'
                    )
                ),
                $('<div>').addClass('sr-item-details').append($('<div>').html(node.find('Beskrivning').text()))
            );
        $('#searchResults').append(div);
    }
});
```

How it essentially works is I grab and cache the xml file, and on a `keyup` event I search the xml file. Any tips on making the performance better? I know that I could require at least 2-3 characters before searching, and even pagination, but I'd rather stay away from those options if at all possible.

Also, it needs to work with all standard browsers including >= IE7

Comment: It's not a [widely used standard](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) but could web workers help? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: should have specified, has to work on all browsers without plugins, including >= IE7

Comment: Are you searching the XML with jQuery? I suggest you use a standard DOMDocument instead and then run some xpath or similar. Additionally so that your question makes more sense, please metric your code and tell the exact place that is running in cycles when your browser got looked up.

Comment: i'm not all that familiar with xpath. how can you use it to search for text?

Comment: You should put the entries into a sorted array, then create a simple index, say based on the first character. If you need more speed, implement a binary search. That way you can search 1,000,000 entries in fewer than 20 lookups, or up to 26,000,000 entries with a simple first character index. I've done it with up to 5,000 entries and it's very quick, even in IE6.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the xml. I don't need the actual content as I understand it may be confidential. But a simple 1 record xml file with lorem ipsum would be fine for performance testing.

Comment: how do you do a binary search over strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to solve this by resetting a timer after each keypress that would delay the search after a certain period of time, say 200-300ms. Once the user stopped typing for a moment, the search would execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an "incremental" search, splitting it with a timer.
In this way your browser doesn't freeze.

Comment: can you fiddle an example?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed
This is a gwt tutorial, but the same logic can be applied to javascript.

Comment: You must do n search on n subsets of your xml, delayed by a timer. the time between two searches is used to the browser to the rendering the UI, and the user doesn't have the sensation of freeze. it's a "simulation" of a scheduler (unfortunately JavaScript is not multi threading) in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<button>search</button>` next to the text box and only search when it has been clicked rather than on every key release.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is, you are using a lot of .find() within a loop, which in itself isn't that well performing. You could write a small jQuery plugin to improve that dramatically.

http://jsperf.com/node-vs-double-select/3

The other thing is, you could convert the xml to json  on the fly, store it in local variable and search through that. Read down the page and find out how they dealt with the same problem on studentlitteratur.se

http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html

You could choose a plugin which allows you to dictate which nodes to include in the conversion and which not.

Then to further optimize it, you could use Modernizr to detect WebWorker support and pass the job to the web worker. But only if browser supports it.